# Scala modify mapValues Set of Strings Delete column

Tags: scala, dictionary

If I have a a `Map` which maps values from `String` to `(String,String,String)`

How can I remove the second `String`from the List that the `Map` would be like `Map( String ->(String,String))`

Example:

```
var mp = Map(
             "K1" -> List("K1_C1","K1_C2","K1_C3"),
             "K2" -> List("K2_C1","K2_C2","K2_C3"),
             "K2" -> List("K3_C1","K3_C2","K3_C3")
            )
```

How can I reach this:

```
Map(
    "K1" -> List("K1_C1","K1_C3"),
    "K2" -> List("K2_C1","K2_C3"),
    "K2" -> List("K3_C1","K3_C3")
   )
```

What I've tried this but didn't work

```
mp.mapValues( _.map(_.drop(2)))
```

Also I've tried to convert the `(String,String,String)` to `List`but It didn't work

```
mp.mapValues(_.map(_.toList.remove(2)))
```

This is like my first time writing in scala because I have to, and I'm tottaly use it like I write Java

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I've edit the question a little bit and Added What I've tried, And I'm doing some tricks currently to see I they could work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close with the `drop` function, but I suggest you take a look at its documentation. It drops the given number of elements from the beginning of the list.

What you actually want is `take` the first one and `takeRight` the last one:

```
mp.mapValues(list => list.take(1) ++ list.takeRight(1))
```

This is pretty ugly, however. If you are certain that your values are always a 3-element list, I suggest pattern matching just as I showed with tuples:

```
mp.mapValues {
  case List(first, _, third) => List(first, third)
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm kind of mis represented my problem, I've edited the question, as the mapValues are `List(String,String,String)`, a huge one and I don't need the middle one because it's the key of the map actually, I wanna get red of it to reduce memory usage as the map is huge

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your map has lists of tuples, not lists of strings. Something like this should work:

```
  m.mapValues { case List((a,b,c)) => (a,c) }
```

or

```
  m.mapValues { case List((a,b,c)) => List((a,c)) }
```

or

```
  m.mapValues { case List((a,b,c)) => List(a,c) }
```

... depending on what type of output you want to end up with.

Comment: @SamehKamal not "also". It is the only one here, that is right. The other answer will not do what you want with the data you described in your question: the first attempt will create lists, each containing two identical tuples, the second one will throw a `MatchError`

Comment: The second piece of code is working, for @Zoltans answer , I've tested it, and It is good.

The first piece was answering my question before being edited.

Comment: If it is working, then the error you mentioned in your question is wrong. It also means that the code in my answer does not work with your data. `List[String]` and `List[(String,String,String)]` are different types.